# Api response white screen flutter in detail page rest api

Tags: flutter, rest, dart

This is where I call API:

```
class Hisseler extends StatefulWidget {
  const Hisseler({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Hisseler> createState() => _HisselerState();
}

class _HisselerState extends State<Hisseler> {

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final url = Uri.parse('https://api.collectapi.com/economy/hisseSenedi');
  var counter;

  Hisselist? hisseResult;

  Future callHisse() async {
    try{
      Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'apikey xxx'
      };
      final response = await http.get(url,headers:requestHeaders);

      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var result = hisselistFromJson(response.body);

        if(mounted);
        setState(() {

          counter = result.result.length;
          result.result.sort((a, b) => (a.text ?? "").compareTo(b.text ?? ""));

          hisseResult = result;
        });
        return result;
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    callHisse();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
            'Hisseler'
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: counter != null ?

          ListView.separated(

              itemCount: counter,

              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Divider(color: Colors.grey[400]);
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    title: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text((hisseResult?.result[index].code ?? "")
                            .replaceAll("https:", ""),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                        Text(hisseResult?.result[index].text??"",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500], fontSize: 14))
                      ],
                    ),
                    trailing: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(hisseResult?.result[index].lastpricestr??"", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                        Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                color:  (hisseResult?.result[index].rate ?? 0) > 0
                                    ? Colors.green
                                    : Colors.red),
                            width: 75,
                            height: 25,
                            child: Text(hisseResult?.result[index].rate.toString()??"",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StocksDetailScreen( text: '', code: '', rate: '', lastpricestr: '',))),
                  ),
                );
              }) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(

          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to create a detail page for this page, I try this as a test:

```
class StocksDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final String rate;
  final String lastpricestr;

  final String code;
  final String text;

  const StocksDetailScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.rate,
    required this.code,
    required this.text,
    required this.lastpricestr,


  }) : super(key: key);



  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(rate,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),),

        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          bottom: true,
          top: false,
          maintainBottomViewPadding: true,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: <Widget>[
                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(rate,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),),                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Divider(height: 3.6,),
                          SizedBox(height: 50,),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(code,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                            ),
                          )



                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),



              // -- Banner ads --

              context.watch<AdsBloc>().bannerAdEnabled == false ? Container()
                  : BannerAdAdmob()   //admob
              //: BannerAdFb()    //fb
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

No errors in the console or anywhere but I get a white screen. How can I fix this?

Comment: try awaiting your callHisse class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it with:

```html
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StocksDetailScreen(
                    degisimoran: hisseResult?.result[index].rate.toString()??"",
                    sondeger: hisseResult?.result[index].lastpricestr??"",
                    hacim: hisseResult?.result[index].hacimstr ?? "",
                    mindeger : hisseResult?.result[index].minstr?? "",
                    maxdeger : hisseResult?.result[index].maxstr?? "",
                    zaman : hisseResult?.result[index].time.toString()?? "",
                    hisseismi : hisseResult?.result[index].text?? "",
                    hissekodu : hisseResult?.result[index].code?? "",


                )),),
```

And on the detail page:

```html
class StocksDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final String degisimoran;
  final String? sondeger;
  final String? hacim;
  final String? mindeger;
  final String maxdeger;
  final String? zaman;
  final String? hisseismi;
  final String? hissekodu;



  const StocksDetailScreen({
Key? key,
required this.degisimoran,
required this.sondeger,
required this.hacim,
required this.mindeger,
required this.maxdeger,
required this.zaman,
required this.hisseismi,
required this.hissekodu,


  }) : super(key: key);
```

Now i can call all data from API.